# Increase EC2 disk storage without losing any data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, devops

I have a `t2.medium` instance running, which has `4GB` of `RAM` and `25GB` of `EBS` volume.

This instance is currently running a `Apache` server, a wordpress app, mysql server and a codeigniter app.

I don't want any data to be lost.

How can I increase the volume to 100GB?

I found an article [here](https://hackernoon.com/tutorial-how-to-extend-aws-ebs-volumes-with-no-downtime-ec7d9e82426e) , but I am not sure if doing so will cause all the data be lost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

we can increase ebs volume without detaching the volume or restarting the instance.
Its good to create a snapshot of your ebs volume in case if something bad happens

for creating snapshot

```
Go to your EBS volume list from your EC2 Dashboard.
Right click the volume.
Click Create Snapshot link.
Add the description value any thing is good here.
Add key : Name and value : snapshot-your-volume.
Click button Create Snapshot.
```

to increase size

```
Right click on the volume you wish to increase.
Add your desired size; In our example type 40.
Click Modify.
You will get confirmation to extend OS file system.
Click Yes.
```

once you finish modifying volume, you need to extend OS file system in order to see the increased volume size.

```
ssh into your instance 
df -h -> will tell you the volume size
lsblk -> display information about the block devices attached to your instance
sudo growpart /dev/xvda 1
df -h -> to verify the size again
sudo resize2fs /dev/xvda1
```

docs for [extending filesystem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html)

Comment: Thanks, it worked but I had to use `xfs_growfs` instead of `resize2fs`.